# Image matching not working for unknown reason

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui, template-matching

I'm using PyAutoGUI's built in OpenCV image matching like this and it returns None every time:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png', greyscale=True, confidence=0.5)
```

- I've tried many different confidences
- I've confirmed that python-opencv is installed on my machine
- I've tested it on Windows and Linux with no luck
- I've made sure that the images are on the screen
- I read through all of the questions I could find to try and fix this with no luck

I'm using the libreoffice icon to test it with no luck. I can't think of what else I would be doing wrong.

Image I'm matching:

[image]

locateOnScreen() just takes a screenshot I believe, so this is the screen it would of been seeing (The screenshot came from pyautogui's screenshot function):

[image]

I also tried this with no luck:

```
pyautogui.screenshot()
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test2.png', confidence=0.5, greyscale=True)
```

Test2.png

[image: Test2.png]

The screenshot that pyautogui takes right before matching:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why PyAutoGui LocateOnScreen() only Returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702511/why-pyautogui-locateonscreen-only-returns-none)

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of your screen?

Comment: I read that question and went through all of the answers with no luck. The things I did primarily came from that question

Comment: Added that screenshot you requested