# Pyautogui image recognition can't recognise image

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to create an Instagram bot that will look for active story's in someones followers but the bot cannot find that even using lower confidence here is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk8Hv.jpg

I've tried to use an bigger sized image but i get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried making the background of the image transparent? Changing the settings of the recognition? Can you please show your current code?

Comment: pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pic\\storyyy.png', confidence=0.8, grayscale=False)

It returns None

Comment: It is already transparent, i've maked it on photoshop

Comment: what if you try confidence = 0.001 ?

Comment: also try the troubleshooting seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702511/why-pyautogui-locateonscreen-only-returns-none

Comment: Using confidence below 0.19 will result in wrong maching, thanks for the link il try adjust the image see if it will work

Comment: if the bot works with a fullscreen browser, did you take the screenshot in fullscreen?